# can't see my picture on the form - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i add Image control to my WebForm.

i insert picture to App_Data.

i connect the picture to my Image control in the ImageUrl

it seen like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="94px" 
            ImageUrl="~/App_Data/Tulips.jpg" Width="209px" />
```

in the design i see this picture, but when i run the project i dont see the picture.

what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App_Data is a special folder in ASP.NET that only must be used to store data and files that aren't intended to be accessed by end users (ie. via a web browser). Try to put your picture in another folder, ie. Images.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it, but it's probably because you put the image in the App_Data folder. That's not the appropriate place for it. Create an images folder and put it there and try again.

Answer (score 0):

App_Data allows you to use a file-based database  that includes SQL Server 2005 and Access,  XML files,Excel worksheets or any file-based data store.
Create a separate folder in your project and place your image in that folder.